# What is the best method to keep third party repositories up to date in my own github repository?

Tags: git, github, repository

I don't have much experience with github.

I'm trying to create my own repository as a compilation that contains some of my own tools and also tools from other third-party repositories.

It is essential that if the authors make updates in their repositories, I can every X time make a pull of all the third-party repositories to have the latest version.

I also need that when my repository is cloned by a user X, both my tools and third-party tools are downloaded locally.

I don't need to make any modifications to the third-party repositories, just update to their latest versions.

I have tried submodules but third party content is not cloned locally when my repository is called.

I have seen that subtrees exist but I know if it will be possible to update all subtrees easily.

Is there a suitable method for this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have tried submodules but third party content is not cloned locally when my repository is called

Submodules should be cloned, provided you use a [`git clone --recurse-submodules`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---recurse-submodulesltpathspecgt):

```
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/<me>/<myRepo>
```

> After the clone is created, initialize and clone submodules within based on the provided pathspec.
> If no pathspec is provided, all submodules are initialized and cloned.

Comment: Thanks. This works. I tried this before but hadn't a good time. Probably because I messed up too much with the .gitmodules and config file so the submodules did not clone properly. However I tried your process in a new environment and worked like a charm.